# Exception while receiving data from client - "End of file" error

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am currently working on a client server TCP/IP application using Boost ASIO.
The client sends data to the server using the following statement

```
boost::system::error_code ignored_error; 
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("Hello World\0"), ignored_error);
```

The server reads this data as such (from an Asynch. read)

```
boost::asio::async_read(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(buf_server),boost::bind(&ServerRead,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Here is where the reading is done

```
boost::array<char, 158> buf_server;

void ServerRead(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: " << buf_server.data() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error occurred." << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However I get the error "End of file".
So now I have two questions

1. How can I resolve this issue. What am i doing wrong here ?
2. Suppose my `buf_server` was only 5 characters instead of 158. How could I make my receiver use this buffer only to read the entire data and `std::cout` it?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior should be expected when you instruct an application to read 158 bytes but only 12 are sent. To resolve this you can send a fixed size header indicating the message size, the [chat client and server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp) example included in the Asio documentation shows how to accomplish this, an excerpt from the client example:

```
void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
  }

  void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error && read_msg_.decode_header())
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_body, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void handle_read_body(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout.write(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length());
      std::cout << "\n";
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, or use a more exotic protocol [such as HTTP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp) where you read until encountering a `\r\n` delimiter.